# Pairwise Linked List issue

Tags: linked-list, swap

Swap Elements in linked list:

Pairwise Swap Elements
start : A > B > C > D > E > Null
End :   B > A > D > C > E > Null

```
Node * pairOne = head;
Node * pairTwo = head.next;

if (pairOne == Null || PairTwo == Null)
return;

while (pairOne & pairTwo){

pairOne.next = pairTwo.next;
pairTwo.next = pairOne;

pairOne = pairOne.next;
pairTwo = pairOne.next;

}
```

Whats wrong with my logic?
I cant seem to figure out why I cant make it B > A > D > C > E > Null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your while loop. In the first iteration, pairOne = A and pairTwo = B, so in the loop you update A.next = C and B.next = A which is correct. You will see the problem in the second iteration when pairOne = C and pairTwo = D, you will update C.next = E and D.next = C, A.next now should point to D instead of C. However in your code, you never update that link, so you will end up with B > A > C > E > NULL. To fix your problem, one way is to keep the previous of pairOne and update its next value too:

```
Node * pairOne = head;
Node * pairTwo = head.next;
Node prev = Null;

if (pairOne == Null || PairTwo == Null)
   return;

while (pairOne & pairTwo){

   pairOne.next = pairTwo.next;
   pairTwo.next = pairOne;
   if (prev) {
      prev.setNext(pairTwo);
   }

   prev = pairOne;
   pairOne = pairOne.next;
   pairTwo = pairOne.next;
}
```

One more thing, you need to update the head too.